# is there a winapi call or keyboard shortcut to enter windows console into "mark" mode?

Tags: winapi, console

Normally user is doing it by clicking right-mouse into console title bar then selecting "edit" and finally "mark". -> http://www.megaleecher.net/Copy_Paste_Text_Dos_Window

So is there a way of doing it from a console application either by sending a message/api call/keyboard sequence to its own window ?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve with this?

Comment: For example a user will click with a mouse on the console (after the program has ended) and it will turn itself into select mode, without walking the menus. I mean this only if app owns the console and not when it is run from command line, and console is owned directly by the cmd interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found: `PostMessage(GetConsoleWindow(), WM_COMMAND, 65522, 0);`

Answer (score 1):

If this is your own application and you want the richer behaviour and flexibility of a windows app rather than a console app, then use a windows app. Otherwise, you can try to automate the steps by simulating the input via `SendInput`. I would advise against doing this because it requires two steps (once for right-click, once to select 'Mark'). This means if someone clicks something else between these two events, your sequence will be broken. Furthermore you are really relying on the automation of an implementation detail which is prone to change at any point.

Looking through the [Console Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it doesn't appear as though anything exists for setting the selection. The closest is going the other way with [GetConsoleSelectionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you want to process the information that is within a console application, a better alternative is to pipe it to your own process and deal with it there.